# Загрузка файла без нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Неприлично как то спрашивать в субботу, каюсь )

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

Выбираем файл, нажимаем загрузить.. все здорово, POST запрос идет. Не могу понять как сделать, что бы после выбора файла ( name='file' ) автоматом шла загрузка, без нажатия на кнопку, и вообще без этой кнопки. Решение напрашивается на JS/JQ, но моих познаний явно не хватает. Подскажите как реализовать?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
</form>
```

p.s. слова для гугла знаю, есть решения в инете, по схеме 10 мегабайт кода, в тысячи файлах.. к сожалению впихать такое решение куда либо проблематично. Ищу какой то оч. простой скрипт

Comment: Нельзя, это была бы большая дыра в безопасности браузера (бери и качай файлы с PC пользователя без его разрешения).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var input = document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
input.onchange = function () {
   this.form.submit();
}
```

Вешаем событие на изменение поля, когда изменилось ( добавили картинку/файл ), делаем `submit` формы

Comment: Извиняюсь.. JQuery подключил, скрипт прописал.. но ничего не произошло. Ест-но попробовал не 1 раз

Comment: Спасибо, что показал куда копать, разобрался. Пример для непонятливых как я тут - http://jsfiddle.net/NbGBj/

Comment: @mixalef, он бы и на чистом js работал, просто в ф-цию `document.querySelector` надо было id, подставить)